# Linker Command Fail in Xcode with Pure Virtual Objects

Tags: c++, xcode, function, virtual

I'm a n00b so correct me on anything.

I've been working on this for a couple days and have done research but can't seem to solve the issue. This is for a programming class that mainly uses Visual Studio and many of my fellow classmates didn't have a problem. Although, I'm on Xcode so maybe it has something to do with that. Basically, I'm creating a Pure Virtual objects called Geometric_Object with child classes Circle.h and Rectangle.h, however when I run the code I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"GeometricObject::GeometricObject()", referenced from:
Circle::Circle() in main.o
Rectangle::Rectangle() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm beyond lost. Because I don't have enough reputation points I can't post all the links so I had to compress them as one on Dropbox. Hopefully someone can bypass this for me so nobody is afraid to unzip the contents.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82764116/Xcode.zip

Comment: You can't "create ... a pure virtual object".  You *can* create a *concrete* object that is a *subclass* of your pure virtual class.  For example: `MyAbstractBaseClass * myObject = new MyConcreteSubclass()`.

Comment: I'm just trying to instantiate the Circle and Rectangle which should <b>not</b> be pure virtual…should they?

Comment: I thought your post said "I'm trying to create a pure virtual object".  I said you couldn't.  So I guess we agree :)  Q: Is "GeometricObject()" an abstract class?  Did you define a constructor for it?  If so, maybe that's the problem: you defined an explicit constructor for "GeometricObject()", but "Circle()" and "Rectangle()" are both looking for the default (zero-argument) constructor.

Comment: Joshua, as a side note, *never* do this in your header file : `using namespace std;` Use fully expended names or class-scoped `using` instead. Also, don't pass by non-const reference for anything your not potentially modifying. (see `setColor` for an example of what I mean should be a `const` reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error says. You haven't defined `GeometricObject::GeometricObject()`. You also haven't defined many other methods in GeometricObject, like the destructor, getColor, setColor etc.

I'm not sure where you think the definitions for these functions are, but they aren't in the code you've linked to.

You have defined (for instance) `Rectangle::Rectangle()`. Just define `GeometricObject::GeometricObject()` in the same way (and all the other missing definitions).

Comment: You said it perfectly: "The problem is exactly what the error says. You haven't defined GeometricObject::GeometricObject()."  However, maybe the OP doesn't *need* a zero argument constructor; maybe he's just declaring or using a variable in a way that the compiler thinks it needs it.  There are many ways this can happen.  For example: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t281655-newbie-constructor-of-the-base-class-not-being-found.html